# Does the RF magnetic field have to be uniformly constant for a coherent EPR signal

Tags: spectroscopy, radio-frequency, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Consider a loop gap resonator for electron paramagnetic resonance which has static (but sweepable) magnetic field in one direction, "x", and a GHz RF magnetic field in a direction "z" that is perpendicular to the static field."

I had assumed that I had built the loop-gap such that the H_z field was constant over the sample volume. We get a reasonable EPR signature from it, can identify some hyperfine components, etc.

I finally got around to doing a finite element for the field and to my surprise, the calculation appears to show that I am generating positive and largely constant Hz on much of the "left" side of the resonator and exactly the opposite Hz on the "right" hand side of the resonator (i.e. negative Hz, with zero field in the middle).

I am now completely confused. I would not have thought such an RF field could give any EPR signature because the spin contribution on the left should cancel that from right. If so then my FEM model is wrong and I need to look there. But maybe not... in which case I need to look into fixing whatever is driving the wrong eigenmode because obviously I will get more signal if all the Hz is uniform.

So that's my question can you get an EPR signal from an Hz which is flat over two areas of the resonator but such that the average Hz is zero? Or maybe in math terms: Given a computation of the RF field in a resonator and a theoretical spectrum of a species, how can I determine the corresponding EPR spectrum of the sample? E.g. does it depend on |H_z| or H_z ?